# Get order address VAT ID via soap api v2 webservice

Tags: magento-1.8, api, customer-address, web-services

How can I get VAT ID for my orders through SOAP API 2?
The field name is vat_id and is visible in order addresses (Billing Address and Shipping Address) like below:

```
John Doe
Company Co.
Street 1
11111 City 
Poland
T: 99879879879 
NIP: 111-11-11-111
```

I use multishipping checkout.
Is it possible to get it?

Part of salesOrderInfo response is below:

```
<shipping_address>
    <parent_id>81</parent_id>
    <address_type>shipping</address_type>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <company>Company Co.</company>
    <street>Street 1</street>
    <city>City</city>
    <postcode>11111</postcode>
    <country_id>PL</country_id>
    <telephone>99879879879</telephone>
    <address_id>162</address_id>
</shipping_address>
<billing_address>
    <parent_id>81</parent_id>
    <address_type>billing</address_type>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <company>Company Co.</company>
    <street>Street 1</street>
    <city>City</city>
    <postcode>11111</postcode>
    <country_id>PL</country_id>
    <telephone>99879879879</telephone>
    <address_id>161</address_id>
</billing_address>
```

It lacks vat_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In February I made a PR to the Magento Hackaton repo in order to add two new SOAP fields for including customer TAX/VAT and email:

https://github.com/magento/hackathon_january_2014/pull/38

To get the TAX/VAT number, You only have to add the following line in the "shoppingCartCustomerEntity" and "shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity" WSDL entities inside app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsdl.xml:

```
<element name="taxvat" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

hope it helps you!

Comment: I only changed name to `vat_id`

Comment: We are closing the repository. This is the change that was in mentioned PR

https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/978394116f7797702ec0c7856d55dc2b

Comment: This is taxvat field on customer model! vat_id is on customer address model and it misses from api also

Answer (score 1):

**To get taxvat in [salesOrderInfo](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html) response through SOAP API**

you have to add this at line **276** in *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml*

```
<element name="taxvat" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

and this at line **278** in *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml*

```
<xsd:element name="taxvat" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for the `taxvat` field - it is indeed missing from `salesOrderInfo`, but it exists in `salesOrderList`.
I guess it's kind of an oversight from Magento API designers as salesOrderInfo is basically the detailed order information and generally contains more order data than salesOrderList (except for `taxvat` field).

Answer (score 0):

Extending @empiricompany answer (don't have enough reputation to comment).

It's not recommended to modify core **Magento** files. Instead, create a **custom module**, especially that it will be a very simple module consisting of basically 1 file. In your custom module add the `wsdl.xml` file inside the `/etc` folder.
In this file you can define the additional fields you want to have in each of the **API types** - if you want to have `vat_id` field in `billing_address` your file should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />          
            <complexType name="salesOrderAddressEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="vat_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

Additional notes:

- Your `wsdl.xml` file will be merged with other `wsdl.xml` files from all the modules that have such file to build the actual WSDL.
- The core Magento file your `wsdl.xml` will be merged with is located at *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml*. You can base on this file copying its fragments to avoid typos.
- As these files are merged, you don't need the full XML from `Mage_Sales` model. You can add only the fragments you need.