# How can I get vat_id via SOAP without additional modifications?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2, vat

I understand that, by default, [Magento doesn't expose the vat_id field via SOAP](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/get-order-address-vat-id-via-soap-api-v2-webservice). The accepted answer there is to edit the core/add a module. Unfortunately, I don't have such luxury because I don't have the filesystem access to Magento: I have just the basic SOAP access and I cannot do any modification.

So: how do I retrive the vat_id via SOAP from a Magento ver. 1.9.4.2?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, '200000006');
$customer = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo($sessionId, '765');
$addresses =  = $proxy->customerAddressList($sessionId, '765');

foreach $addresses:
  $proxy->customerAddressList($sessionId, '211');
```

Unfortunately, the vat_id is nowhere to be seen.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution: copy the `vat_id`to the `taxvat` field in the checkout page, then use `taxvat` from SOAP:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('change', '#billing\\:vat_id', function() {

        var vat = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#billing\\:taxvat').val(vat);
    });
</script>
```

(jQuery required)